# Calculate angle with XYZ + rotation and my enemy his XYZ + rotation [Linear Algebra]

Tags: c++, linear-algebra

Tally-ho chaps,

This question considers the art of linear algebra a place in math where I fall short to solve this. So I am hoping you guys could help me out :D.

I am trying to create a singleplayer autokicker cheat for a game called mount and blade. The goal of this autokicker is to always successfully kick the player using the power of math. I managed to achieve a lot of things thanks to the help of the internet (aimbot,esp,...) but now I am kinda stuck since I don't know enough linear algebra to get angles etc. These are the things I have

- My XYZ (player position)
- Rotation starting from coordinate (0,0) radians converted to degrees (-180;180)
- Enemy XYZ and rotation

A player can successfully kick another player if the distance is less than
1 float and the player is in front of the other player. Hence why I need to calculate the angle between the direction I am looking and the enemy his XYZ. I will draw in paint what [I want to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuYXp.png)

[image]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SVfW.png]

[These are the values displayed in game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SVfW.png) first is calculated distance next is enemy rotation and last is my rotation. I think rotation is done on the 0,0 spot

Any help is appreciated and awarded with a massive thumbs up :D!

```
float Distance(D3DXVECTOR3 vector1, D3DXVECTOR3 vector2)
{
    return sqrt(pow((vector1.x - vector2.x), 2) + pow((vector1.y - vector2.y), 2) + pow((vector1.z - vector1.z), 2));
}
 
bool AutoKick()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cPlayerBase.size(); i++)
    {
        float DistanceToLocalPlayer = Distance(cPlayerBase[i]->vec, mainPlayer.vec); // vec is X Y Z
        float number = Rad2Deg(atan2(cPlayerBase[i]->vecRotation[1], cPlayerBase[i]->vecRotation[0])); // X Y rotation
       
        if(cPlayerBase[i]->address == mainPlayer.pointer ) 
        std::cout << "My degree -- " << number;
        if (DistanceToLocalPlayer != 0.0f)
        {
            std::cout << "Enemy Distance -- " << DistanceToLocalPlayer << "Enemy degree -- " << number;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This topic would get more traction within the games or math exchange group.

Comment: Tried Math nobody responded :( and I don't think game devs are very helpfull towards cheating even if for singleplayer

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking but it sounds like you want to calculate the angle between two 3d vectors. Use the [geometric definition)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition) of cosine.

Comment: can't just do that if I do that I can face the enemy with my back it would still be valid as a kick I need to take rotation into consideration as well so my question is how do I do that

Comment: If you just want in front or not then rather than calculating an angle you only need to check sign of the dot product. Greater than 0 -> in front, less than 0 -> behind, exactly 0 -> exactly to the side. If you do need an angle over a 2pi range then you need to use atan2.

Comment: I can rotate on the spot without changing the X Y Z so checking only on X Y Z is never going to work I think

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. The dot product I described is between the direction the player is looking and the a vector from the player to the enemy. Does that help? Maybe the confusion is what exactly is meant by one player being "in front" of another? Does it mean looking at or walking towards?

Comment: yh mate I just started reading it precisely what I need thank you :D now I need to test it out see if it works

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of dot product as capturing the "similarity" of two vectors. Two vectors that are exactly parallel have a dot product equal to the product of their magnitudes, vectors pointing "somewhat" in the same direction have a positive dot product, exactly perpendicular vectors have no common components and have a dot product of 0, vectors point "somewhat" in opposite directions have a negative dot product, and two vectors that are exactly antiparallel have a dot product equal to the negative product of their magnitudes.

To see if one player is in front of another, create a vector pointing in the direction the first player is looking and another vector pointing from the first player to the second. If their dot product is positive, the second player is in front of the first. That is, a vector in the direction the first player is looking is similar to a vector from the first to the second player.

There is no need to explicitly calculate an angle.

Comment: That's exactly it. @Mercenary_Frank Once you get it working, be sure to get banned quickly, cheater ;)

Comment: I hate cheaters aswell I don't use this to ruin the fun for other people but simple to have a laugh when I am fighting one of my mates. My enjoyment lies in building these kind of program not using it to be a scumbag in the server. Making these kind of programs really help me get better in math where I otherwise am totally not good at lol thx for the answer magical cat :D! also this cheat is open source on github https://github.com/FrancescoVentura/Mount-and-Blade-Internal-ESPCheat

Comment: @Praxeolitic could you give me a formula I tried `Length(player)*Length(enemy)*cos(Rad2Deg(rotation))` like it says on the wikipage but it doesn't give the correct result :(

Comment: x0*x1 + y0*y1 + z0*z1 (just dot product, you don't need to calculate the angle itself)

Comment: @Praxeolitic nope that isn't it `return enemy.x*v.x + enemy.y*v.y + enemy.z*v.z;` where atan2(v.y,v.x)*180/PI = degrees between -180 and 180. The vector V are the coordinates for my rotation. Maybe you can see what I am doing wrong :(

Comment: `enemy` is from player to enemy and `v` is a vector pointing where the player is looking, is that right? You don't need to use any trig functions if you only need to determine in "front of". Just check if that product is positive.

Comment: `float CalculateAngle(D3DXVECTOR3 player, D3DXVECTOR3 enemy, D3DXVECTOR3 v)
{
 float x = player.x - enemy.x;
 float y = player.y - enemy.y;
 float z = player.z - enemy.z;

 return x*v.x + y*v.y + z*v.z;
}` The number is always negative. Maybe there is something wrong with V? How can you check if that vector is pointing where the players is looking? I just used atan2 and got my degrees from it. xd

Comment: It should be `enemy.x - player.x`, etc. (displacement from player to enemy). `v` points in the direction the player is looking, right? If so, this is the correct dot product and you just need to check if it's positive.

Comment: @Mercenary_Frank I don't know exactly what data the game makes available so I'm not sure how to get a vector in the direction the player is looking. You could check if your `v` is in that direction by calculating `(enemy.x - player.x, enemy.y - player.y, enemy.z - player.z)`, normalizing that vector, normalizing your v, and then comparing to see that they're about equal.

Comment: For somebody that should read this thread what Praxeolitic said didn't work for me instead I asked on unknowncheats and used the following formula  `return acos( (x*v.x + y*v.y+z*v.z) / ( (Length(D3DXVECTOR3(x, y, z))*Length(v) )));` gives me the angle like I described above but thanks anyway @Praxeolitic

Comment: What @Praxeolitic said is almost exactly what the function you received is doing - the main difference being it takes the final dot product and converts it back to an angle - which from your original problem, is not needed.  Just knowing the value is positive means the player is in front of you and the magnitude gives the less than 1.  The formulat given is based on: cos(angle between vectors) = (v1 dot v2) / (magnitide v1 * magnitude v2) where magnitude is "length".  The original answer was fine.